# Send pdf with smba trafficmanager or botframework

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I'm trying to send pdf file as attachment proactively to teams user with *https://smba.trafficmanager.net/in/v3/conversations/* and attachment format as below

```
"attachments": [
        {
            "contentType": "application/pdf",
            "contentUrl": "http://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf",
            "name": "sample.pdf",
            "content": {
                "uniqueId": "1150D938-8870-4044-9F2C-1213213123",
                "fileType": "pdf"
            }
        }
    ]
```

I'm able to send txt files but not pdf, every time I'm getting

```
{"error":{"code":"BadArgument","message":"Unknown attachment type"}}
```

Is there any other contentType other than application/pdf ?

Comment: Have you considered rather uploading the file to the Files tab (i.e. to SharePoint) and then just posting a message with a link?

Comment: Yes i agree with Hilton here. I would tried something in the same lines:

{
    "body": {
        "contentType": "html",
        "content": "Here's the latest budget. <attachment id=\"153fa47d-18c9-4179-be08-9879815a9f90\"></attachment>"
    },
    "attachments": [
        {
            "id": "153fa47d-18c9-4179-be08-9879815a9f90",
            "contentType": "reference",
            "contentUrl": "https://m365x987948.sharepoint.com/sites/test/Shared%20Documents/General/test%20doc.pdf",
            "name": "Budget.pdf"
        }
    ]
}

Comment: Does it helped?

Comment: @Hilton, files tab is my lost option, I'm trying to find a way to upload pdfs bot to a conversation just like how a user uploads attachments to a conversation

Comment: @Dev thank you for the help, will try and let you know

Comment: Cool . Good to hear @kiran

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with Hilton and Dev here. I think it's more convenient to post messages with card attachments referencing existing SharePoint files using the Microsoft Graph APIs.

[MS documents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/bot-v3/bots-files) referred to 2 ways for bots send attachment. **Using the Microsoft Graph APIs works for bots in all scopes in Teams while using the Teams APIs works only in the personal context.**

By the way, the document says pdf is ok to be a file type.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

@kiran, The below payload works for me. So i am adding the payload for your convenience (below), so that you can copy/test it.

```html
{ "body": { "contentType": "html", "content": "Here's the latest budget. <attachment id=\"153fa47d-18c9-4179-be08-9879815a9f90\"></attachment>" }, "attachments": [ { "id": "153fa47d-18c9-4179-be08-9879815a9f90", "contentType": "reference", "contentUrl": "m365x987948.sharepoint.com/sites/test/Shared%20Documents/…", "name": "Budget.pdf" } ] }
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the discussion in the comments, it is definitely better to rather provide a link to the document, hosted in SharePoint (files tab) - that's exactly what the Files tab is intended for, rather than every user having to download their own copy. In addition, have a look at the topic of [Link Unfurling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/messaging-extensions/how-to/link-unfurling?tabs=dotnet) to see how to provide a better embedded experience for the posted file.